# Splunk -> Get time taken in milliseconds

Tags: splunk

I have splunk json log entries that have epochSecond , nanoOfSecond, eventid and message fields.
I want to find average , 95perc etc. of time taken in milliseconds for an event(which is defined by a unique eventid across all log entries) which is the difference between the time of first log entry and last log entry of an event.

How do I go about doing this in Splunk? I can't even get duration of each event in milliseconds to start with

stats range(_time) as duration by eventid -> seems to give time ins seconds, not millisec
stats range(timestamp) as duration by eventid -> Gives nothing
stats range(epochSecond * 1000000000 + nanoOfSecond) as duration by eventid -> gives syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Splunk, _time is a seconds counter so `stats range(_time)` will be a number of seconds.

If the timestamp field is something like "2020-11-11 09:27" then `stats range(timestamp)` makes no sense since there's no such thing as a range of strings (at least not in Splunk).

Try `stats range(eval(epochSecond*1000000000 + nanoOfSecond))`.